# Development with SQL Data Source in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, 2013, sql-server

There is a sql database. I want to get datas and display them as a list. And I want to filter the datas too. But I can't find any basic tutorial to do it. I don't know where to begin. Where should I put them? I created an empty SP 2013 Project but then what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could start from this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fp161238.aspx

Comment: Thanks for replying. How can I use my database instead of http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/  ?

Comment: you could create a BCS service